# Running a rails project upon computer restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu

I was able to run my rails project at first, but then after I restarted my computer, I cannot run it any more. For the errors kindly refer to the following screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExGKm.jpg

Thank you for any help!

Comment: It appears you are using Windows - is this right? what system are you using? where is ruby stored on it?

Comment: I am using linux (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the gem nio4r requires you to have ruby header files installed. Run this then try again:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks man. Though I'm still wondering why I encountered such error since I was able to run it the first time.